# How to return value only if a if statement is true?

Tags: python

So I got a piece of code that is providing me with some headache.

```
def Handy():
    print "\nMöchten Sie ein neues Handy?"
    print "\n1 - Ja\n2 - Nein"

    handy = raw_input(">>> ")

    if handy == "2":
        print "\nSie möchten kein neues Handy"
    elif handy == "1":
        wunschhandy = raw_input("\nBitte geben Sie den Namen des Handys ein: ")
    else:
        Handy()
    return handy, wunschhandy
```

If I choose option `"1"` everything is ok. But if I go for `"2"` it gives me this error: `"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'wunschhandy' referenced before assignment"`

I know why it is happening, or at least I think I know why. It is because the var `wunschhandy` has not been decleared, because I used option `"2"`.

So how do I solve this problem? Is there a way to only return a value, if it has been assigned by the right if choice?

Comment: Do you really want to return either the string "2" or a 2-tuple containing "1" and something else? What does the caller do with the return values?

Comment: Not completely related to your question, but when you call `Handy()` in the `else` block, you don't do anything with the result. You probably want `return Handy()`. (Also, making the function repeat by calling itself will cause it to crash if the user enters incorrect input 500 times in a row. But that's not likely to be a practical issue.)

Comment: No, I do not want to return the function. I just want to run it agian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would set `wunschhandy = None` before the `if` statement.

In this case you have a defined value, and the caller can test for it.

Another option would be

```
if handy == "2":
    print "\nSie möchten kein neues Handy"
    return handy,
elif handy == "1":
    wunschhandy = raw_input("\nBitte geben Sie den Namen des Handys ein: ")
    return handy, wunschhandy
else:
    Handy()
```

which returns a tuple of length 2 for option 1 and a tuple of length 1 for option 2. The caller can easily test that.

Besides, instead of calling `Handy()` recursively, I would put a loop inside it. Otherwise you might end in a stack overflow error...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return `wunschhandy` only if the user chooses "1", then place the return statements within the if blocks

```
def Handy():
    print "\nMöchten Sie ein neues Handy?"
    print "\n1 - Ja\n2 - Nein"

    handy = raw_input(">>> ")

    if handy == "2":
        print "\nSie möchten kein neues Handy"
        return handy
    elif handy == "1":
        wunschhandy = raw_input("\nBitte geben Sie den Namen des Handys ein: ")
        return handy, wunschhandy
    else:
        Handy()
        //do you want to return Handy()?
```

Answer (score 0):

Just based on the small snippet of code you provided, it seems the 'wunschhandy' variable is only being defined if 'handy == "1"', but this variable is being returned at the end. I would set wunschhandy equal to null above the if statement so the variable is defined before trying to return it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the variable `wunschhandy` is returned before it is declare. Only if you enter 1 it is declared. You may declare the `wunschhandy` before the if statements and assign it a defualt value.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialise `wunschhandy`, so it's in the scope:

```
def Handy():
    handy = raw_input("Moechten Sie ein neues Handy?\n1 - Ja\n2 - Nein\n>>> ")

    wunschhandy =  None
    if handy is "2" :
        print "\nSie moechten kein neues Handy"
    elif handy is "1" :
        wunschhandy = raw_input("\nBitte geben sie den Namen des Handys ein: ")
    else :
        Handy()
    return handy, wunschhandy
```